# Check if React Bootstrap Form is filled in or not to conditionally disable submit button

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-form

We have the following contact form in React using https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/overview/

```
let contactForm =
    (<Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={sendEmail} className='toggle-contact-form'>
        <div className='toggle-contact-form__header'>
            <p className='p1'>Please Reach out!</p>
            <p className='p2'>Use our contact form to reach out with any questions, concerns or issues with the website.</p>
        </div>

        <Form.Row style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='name'>
                <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control className='cbb-home-input' placeholder='required' />
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='email'>
                <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control className='cbb-home-input' type='email' placeholder='required' />
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='phone'>
                <Form.Label>Phone Number</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control className='cbb-home-input' placeholder='optional' />
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='message'>
                <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control className='cbb-home-input' as='textarea' rows='2' placeholder='required' />
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='button'>
                <Button variant='primary' type='submit' disabled={true}>
                    {isSubmitting ? 'Sending Email...' : 'Submit'}
                </Button>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
    </Form>);
```

Currently the button `disabled={true}`, we'd like to make this conditional on the `Form.Control` elements for `name`, `message` both being not empty, and `email` being a valid email address. Currently we have no form validation. Is it possible to validate this form as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/validation/) suggest using a library to make this process easier:

> It's often beneficial (especially in React) to handle form validation via a library like Formik, or react-formal. In those cases, isValid and isInvalid props can be added to form controls to manually apply validation styles.

##### But here's how you can do it without a library:

Since we need access to the values of the input fields, we'll need to use [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) to hold the form data. First we will set up some `useState` variables to hold the data:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
```

Then we need to use those state variables to handle the data in form fields by setting the `value` and `onChange` props:

```
...

<Form.Control
value={name}
onChange={(e) => {
  setName(e.target.value);
}}
className="cbb-home-input"
placeholder="required"
/>

...

<Form.Control
  value={email}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  }}
  className="cbb-home-input"
  type="email"
  placeholder="required"
/>

...

<Form.Control
  value={message}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setMessage(e.target.value);
  }}
  className="cbb-home-input"
  as="textarea"
  rows="2"
  placeholder="required"
/>

...
```

Now that we have access to the form field data, we can create a variable to keep track of whether the user input is valid:

```
const isValid = checkValidity(name, message, email);
```

The `checkValidity` function can check if `name`, `message`, and `email` meet the requirements we want them too:

```
const checkEmail = (email) => {
  return /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/.test(email);
};

const checkValidity = (name, message, email) => {
  return !!name && !!message && checkEmail(email);
};
```

At this point, the `isValid` variable will always be updated with whether or not the current user input in the form is valid. Specifically, we are making sure `name` and `message` are not empty, and that `email` passes a simple regex validity check.

Finally, we disable the submit button whenever `isValid` is false using the `disabled` prop:

```
<Button variant="primary" type="submit" disabled={!isValid}>
   {isSubmitting ? "Sending Email..." : "Submit"}
</Button>
```

Here's a full working example on CodeSandbox: [image: Edit Form Validity Check]